# Map/Reduce gives me NaN or wrong result (due to null)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I am yet to ask another Map/Reduce question.

I have a collection "`example`" which looks like this:

```
{
"userid" : "somehash",
"channel" : "Channel 1"
}
```

My Map/Reduce functions look like this:

```
var map = function () {
    emit(this.channel, {user:this.userid, count: 1});
}

var reduce = function (key, values) {
    var result = {total:0, unique:0};
    var temp = [];
    values.forEach(function (value) {
        result.total += value.count;

        if (temp.indexOf(value.user) == -1) {
            temp.push(value.user);
        }
    });

    result.unique += temp.length;

    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately, it gives me some really strange results:

```
{ "_id" : "Channel 1", "value" : { "total" : NaN, "unique" : 47 } }
{ "_id" : "Channel 2", "value" : { "total" : NaN, "unique" : 12 } }
{ "_id" : "Channel 3", "value" : { "total" : 6, "unique" : 6 } }
```

And it seems like `value.count` resolves to `null`, it also seems like "Unique" isn't the correct value as well. What I want to do is to count all the values for each channel and also calculate it in such a way that I can see an unique value for each user. Which means, a document in this collection, `example`, may occur several times. I want to know all times AND unique times.

I followed this guide: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-ReduceFunction and I don't know why I get `null` thrown in my face? Very strange, any good ideas on the subject?

Thanks for the advice and better wisdom.

Comment: what `values` are you passing to `reduce`? are they strings? objects? what is `value.count`?

Comment: Im passing this: `{
"userid" : "somehash",
"channel" : "Channel 1"
}` as noted in top. Userid is a string and value.count is 1 (integer) as you may see from the code.

Comment: Actually the `values` you are passing that @jbabey asked about are `{'user' : 'userid', 'count' : 1}`, the channel is the key. Can you post your input into the map, or at least an example of it?

Comment: can you even use `.forEach` on an object?

Comment: The reduce phase gathers all of the results from the maps that have the same key, so I think that values should be an array of objects in the form posted above

Comment: instead of values.foreach(function (value) {} , try using for(value in values){}

Comment: @HunterMcMillen What do you mean by "input into the map"?

Comment: The data that the map emits comes from somewhere, I was just asking to see an example of it.

Comment: @cubsink that will not work, because then the `count` property will become one of the `value` items in the loop, and `count.count` does not exist (which is where the `NaN` is coming from)

Comment: @jbabey, parvin: According to the linked docs, the data is converted into an Array of values, which would be why the `.forEach` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because map/reduce sometimes fires over itself, i.e. reduce is fired over the result of reduce. But result of reduce does not have `count` field. You must always make sure that map emit and reduce result have **the same** format. Read more about this in documentation.

**EDIT** Here's a simple demonstration how you can fix this:

```
var map = function () {
    emit(this.channel, { user: [this.userid], count: 1 });
}

var reduce = function (key, values) {
    var result = { user: [], count: 0 };
    values.forEach(function (value) {
        result.count += value.count;

        value.user.forEach(function(usr) {
            if (result.user.indexOf( usr ) == -1) {
                result.user.push( usr );
            }
        });
    });

    return result;
}
```

Now `result.user.length` should give you unique users. Didn't test it, but it should work.

**EDIT 2** It should be slow though, `.indexOf` is a quite expensive function. You can make it faster by making two map/reduce jobs. First you map/reduce over the collection like this:

```
var map = function() {
    // make a key unique per channel and userid
    emit( this.channel + '_' + this.userid,
        { count: 1, channel: this.channel }
    );
}

var reduce = function(key, values) {
    var result = { count: 0, channel: null };
    values.forEach(function( value ) {
        result.count += value.count;
        // Don't worry about these substitutions,
        // these values can't change anyway per key.
        result.channel = value.channel;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Now `count` over this collection will give you number of unique entries. To get the total number you do second map/reduce over results like this:

```
var map = function() {
    // Note the key!!!
    emit( this.value.channel, { count: this.value.count } );
}

var reduce = function(key, values) {
    var result = { count: 0 };
    values.forEach(function( value ) {
        result.count += value.count;
    });
    return result;
}
```

This should be a lot faster.

Comment: Does this mean the naming must be the same or just the type or both? :)

Comment: @cubsink I've updated my answer. Entire structure of emit in map and result in reduce must be the same.

Comment: It works well, your answer, but it's extremely slow. I use a cron job to aggregate 2 collections like this and even if I started it for 50 minutes ago, it's not done. Is it possible to make it quicker in any way and still have the unique values?

Comment: @cubsink I've updated the answer. This cannot be done efficiently without double map/reduce.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I'll try it first thing tomorrow. I wish I could upvote your answer ten times. :)

Comment: This works fantastically well. Thank you so much for this, I love you.

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-ReduceFunction):

> Because the reduce function might be invoked more than once for the same key, the structure of the object returned by the reduce function must be identical to the structure of the map function's emitted value

You don't do that, your reduce returns an object with `total` and `unique` instead of `count` and `user`. Either you change your format to one that represents the grouping by user, or you use a [finalize function](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-FinalizeFunction).